# Firebase query startAt() doesnt return any value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my chat app.i want to receive only recently added messages so i am trying to receive message via query startAt() but the query return no data.

please help me to find out where i making a mistake:

this is my data structure: ([My Datastructure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJjMu.png))

-Chats
-TrHRsy8x7WYZjodQrNrzfumw16z2g2dojhGBdie07PXqhl47l8GWN1a2
-LastMessage
-Messages
-MCi-gOmhLUl5MuLtCiI
-MCi-hstmFyAfAczexvI
LT: -11108656
T: 1595278548931
c: 2
m: "hi"
r: "g2dojhGBdie07PXqhl47l8GWN1a2"
s: "TrHRsy8x7WYZjodQrNrzfumw16z2"
-MCi-kukmwJpU3ubswId

```
  Query ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats/" + uniquechatid()).child("Messages").orderByChild("T").startAt("1595278548931");

        receiveListener = ref2.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) 
            {
                if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    assert chat != null;
                    Log.e("chat added",chat.getM());
                }
            }
});
```

i want to receive only messages from those timestamp.i even tried the startAt(value,key) .startAt() doesnt work.if i remove startAt() then data receives perfectly.

my message uploading:

```
  private void sendMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message) {

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
        hashmap.put("s", sender);
        hashmap.put("r", receiver);
        hashmap.put("m", message);
        hashmap.put("c", 1);
        hashmap.put("T",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        hashmap.put("LT",timenow);

        reference.child("Chats/"+uniquechatid()+"/Messages").push().setValue(hashmap);
       
    }
```

my database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
     "Chats": {
       "$chatid":{
         "Messages":{
         "$messageid":{
           ".indexOn": "T"  
         }   
         }
       }
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a child of Messages in the pic. You ref2 should be like

```
Query ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats/" + uniquechatid()).child("Messages/" +"MCi-hstmFyAfAczexvI").orderByChild("T").startAt("1595278548931");

    receiveListener = ref2.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) 
        {
            if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                assert chat != null;
                Log.e("chat added",chat.getM());
            }
        }
```

});

provide message id or the id you are using to store different messages as the child of Messages.

Comment: Can you help me how can I access to those unique chatid that was generated by firebase to attach in my  query.

Comment: sure! Please show your full code where you are uploading the messages.

Comment: Like you are doing with the chat to get to the `uniquechatid()`, to that same thing for the messages also.It is not able to reach to `T`

Comment: Okay thank you so much.first I ll try this method now and check if it works and then I ll come back if I have doubt.

Comment: No problem meanwhile you can give me an upvote if it was useful :p

Comment: No it didn't work.still no data received. Please help me.can you check if I making any mistake with the database rules.

Comment: No! those are not rules. You should go to https://console.firebase.google.com/ open your project and then go to database selction from left sidebar and change the database to firebase database and then go to rules. your rules should look like `"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }`

Comment: And `"$messageid"` is what you need after you update the rules.

Comment: Yeah I know.i just copied only part of the rules for convenience.

Comment: No that is creating confusions please paste all the code that is there in rules.

Comment: Updated my full rules.sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the other methods that I can get only recently added messages from database.